# Spark Error - Value Text file not a member of org.apache.spark.sparkcontext

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have just started with Apache Spark. When I try to RDD a File I get the

```
error :
Value Textfile not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext.
```

This is what I typed :

```
val data1 = sc.textfile("README.md")
```

I have **AmazonEMR** with Spark on it.

Answer (score 5):

Ok Just found that is case sensitive. that needs to be `textFile` (with **F** Cap).
I hope this will help someone.